# JWT Token does not make me logged in Django

Tags: python, django, api, axios, token

**Hello Guys**
I am trying to log in with simpleJWT of django. When I log in it gives me access_token and refresh_token. But it is not making me logged in. My django-server still says `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute ...` when I try to view some api endpoints
I am sending post request for login via axios in React. **Here is my `login.jsx`**

```
import axiosInstance from "../../axios";
...
state = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        loggedIn: false,
    };
    handleLogin = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        axiosInstance
            .post(`auth2/token/`, {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                localStorage.getItem("access_token", res.data.access);
                localStorage.getItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh);
                axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] =
                    "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("access_token");
                this.setState({
                    loggedIn: true,
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    };
...
```

### **this is my `axios.js` file from react project**

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/";
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            ? "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
            : null,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    },
});
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance
```

### **This is my `views.py` file from django project**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from datetime import datetime
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    message = "Server is live current time "
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=message+date)


class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**This is `settings.py` file**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=14),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT', 'Bearer'),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

**Pls. Help guys. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Read this section:

[AUTH_HEADER_TYPES](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#auth-header-types)

Update:

```
'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',)
```

and,

```
axiosInstance.defaults.headers["Authorization"] = 
"Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("access_token");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error
I used `getItem("access_token", res.data.access)` instead of `setItem(.....`